# Why is RowNumber not working as expected? (Report builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that uses a simple bit of SQL

```
SELECT 


      [User Name]

      ,[Activity]

    ,(cast(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, left(cast(([Activity End Time]-[Activity Start Time])as time),8)))as int)) as [seconds difference]

  FROM [iPR].[dbo].[TimeRecordingStatus]

   where [Activity Start Time] between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

This produces a matrix report that looks like this. I have used "Name" as the group name grouping on [User_Name].

[image: report]

I am trying to enumerate the rows in the "Name" group so that I can alternate colours to make it a bit easier to read. The expression I used in the Rownumber column is

```
=rownumber("Name")
```

I am expecting to see an ordered list from 1 to x but instead I get this. Which I can't even begin to parse why it would be in this order? Why 7 then 14 then 7? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The group has no filters just Group on [User_Name] and Sort By [User_Name] a to z.

[image: weird output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use RowNumber as this looks at the dataset rather than what is displayed. What you actually need to do is get the number of unique ItemID's on or before each group.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ItemId.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

Here is one of my example

[image]

docs for ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-runningvalue-function?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This worked perfectly for my username list. Using this as the Fill expression =iif(right(RunningValue(Fields!User_Name.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1")/2,2) = ".5","PaleTurquoise","LightGrey") but when I tried the same expression on my other columns I got this error The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘seconds_difference1’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the Tablix ‘Tablix1’.

Comment: error explains all, you cannot use  RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous for filling background color, you might have to user ReortItem i.e textbox value rather than expression for your further manipulation. But I believe you are close to your solution as you have seq number based on your username field.

Comment: but the same expression works for the User Name column so it must be something to do with the scope perhaps?

Comment: Took your advice and went for the reportitem mode. Put an invisible column with this expression =RunningValue(Fields!User_Name.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1") and then used =iif(right((reportitems!Textbox24.value/2),2)=".5" , "PaleTurquoise","LightGrey") for the fill. TYVM

Comment: This is great and works well for figuring out alternate row color in a grouped values tables. Cheers